# Django unable to find MySQLdb python module

Tags: python, django, mysql

Installed Django from source (python setup.py install and such), installed MySQLdb from source (python setup.py build, python setup.py install). Using Python 2.4 which came installed on the OS (CentOS 5.5). Getting the following error message after launching the server:

```
Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

The pythonpath the debug info provides includes

```
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages'
```

and yet, if I `ls` that directory, I can plainly see

```
MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.4-linux-i686.egg
```

Using the python interactive shell, I can type `import MySQLdb` and it produces no errors. This leads me to believe it's a Django pathing issue, but I haven't the slightest clue where to start looking as I'm new to both Django and python.

EDIT: And to be a bit more specific, everything is currently running as root. I haven't setup any users yet on the machine, so none exist other than root.

EDITx2: And to be even more specific, web server is Cherokee, and deploying using uWSGI. All installed from source.

Comment: just do this ------------apt-get install python-mysqldb

Answer (score 33):

Have you considered installing MySQLdb from python packages?
I would also recommend doing this with `pip` instead of `easy_install`.

First you can replace `easy_install` with `pip`:

```
easy_install pip
pip install pip --upgrade
```

And then install Django via PIP:

```
pip install MySQL-python
pip install Django
```

Typically `easy_install` is installed already (part of setuptools), while pip is much better. It offers uninstallation options too, and uses flat install directories instead of the EGG files magic. This might resolve some incompatibilities as well.

Comment: Trying to run "easy_install install pip" gives me this error: Searching for install |Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/install/
Couldn't find index page for 'install' (maybe misspelled?)

Comment: @irishb: whoops, my bad. `easy_install` doesn't need a `install` verb first. fixed!

Answer (score 17):

Did you try building the dependencies? This solved it for me on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
pip install MySQLdb-python
```

Comment: this worked for me, but rather with `pip install mysql-python` (i.e. without the "db"), on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me (Linux Mint):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev (this was the key for me)
pip install mysql-python
pip install django
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out where Python is looking for it's libraries by invoking "python manage.py shell" from the directory base of your Django project. Then do:

```
import sys
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

And you'll see where the python is pulling libraries from. Also try to do a "import mysql" to see if that's kicking out an error.

Finally, the pathing for the WSGI service is (likely) configured with the uWSGI setup in Cherokee - sorry, I don't know the details of that critter to make suggestions on how to determine where/how it's loading the library path.

Comment: Hmm interesting, running python manage.py shell results in that same error I'm getting.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Comment: Then it's definitely something in the python pathing. Did looking at the output of pprint.pprint(sys.path) provide any insight into where it's looking (or not) that you expected to include the Egg that you mentioned at the very top?

Comment: Okay, my mistake. I forgot that I had deleted the .egg temporarily while debugging something. I just put it back (reinstalled MySQLdb) and I can run manage.py shell now. The output of pprint showed that it's looking directly at the .egg: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.4-linux-i686.egg

Weird. Anyway, going to the page Cherokee runs still produces the No MySQLdb module error. EDIT: Thanks for your help thus far! Everyone else I've asked so far have been unable to even get this far.

Comment: I guess the next thing I'd try to do is get the output from sys.path onto an HTML page some how through Cherokee to see what's going on with it's pathing. I would think it has to be different, but I'm getting a bit stuck now without knowing Cherokee.

Comment: Hm, yeah I'm not sure how to get that done either. Will have to dig around Cherokee's documentation or ask them on IRC. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, but it was only an issue inside a virtualenv.

What I did to finally fix it was

```
workon [project_name]
pip uninstall django
pip install mysql-python
pip install django
```

So making sure you install `mysql-python` before `django` seems to work.
This is on a Ubuntu system and using `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using 
linux:-  sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

windows:- pip install python-mysqldb    or
          easy_install python-mysqldb

Hope this should work

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

in my case, Python was able to access mySQL, but Django (1.6) gave the error: "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb"

I am on a Macbook OSX (Maverick), by the way.

When I tried to run

`pip install mysql-python`

I got an error during compilation : "clang: error: unknown argument: ‘-mno-fused-madd’ [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]."

The problem, it turns out, is an updated behavior of cc compiler with the new Xcode 5.1. When there is a parameter it doesn't recognize, considers it as a fatal error and quits. The solution to override this behavior can be found here:

http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

Answer (score -1):

This issue was the result of an incomplete/incorrect installation of the MySQL for Python adapter.
Specifically, I had to edit the path to the `mysql_config` file to point to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`.
Discussed in greater detail in this article:
 http://dakrauth.com/blog/entry/python-and-django-setup-mac-os-x-leopard/