# Installing MySQLdb 1.2.3 with Python For Django on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, mysql-python

I am a beginner Java developer and newbie to Python and I want to install Django and from what i understood that i need to install MySQLdb 1.2.3 with Python and I have MySQL already installed so I am trying to do so and all the guides I find is for 1.2.2 and what I did after installing is

```
sudo python setup.py
```

and this is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

So, is there a simple guide I can follow or a fix to that error to get MySQLdb installed and running ?

By the way I am using Lion.

Update 1 : i've found this tutorial and followed it [Here](http://djangrrl.com/post/installing-django-with-mysql-on-mac-os-x/) and the result now i get when i run and i've downloaded the version 1.2.2 and did the work on it

```
python setup.py build
```

that's what i get

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,2,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.2 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

So what can i do ?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named setuptools`: this error means that a module named `setuptools` isn't installed or is misplaced, get it [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

Comment: I dunno if you absolutely HAVE to build it from source, but I have found the easiest way to get it to work for me on Lion was to use pip to install it. See this StackOverflow's answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243073/django-unable-to-find-mysqldb-python-module

Comment: EDIT: Weird double post, and it won't let me delete the second now...

Comment: the pip method when i write     easy_install pip    i get an error

Comment: i tried the pip method and it can't find the mysql_config file,by the way i've updated the issue

Comment: You need XCode 4 from Apple. Available at the App Store for free.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all components were built for the same architecture. A 32 bit MySQL only works with 32bit Python. Unfortunately lion only supports 64bit MySQL.

I just ended up using [mariadb](https://mariadb.org/). That was much easier than installing MySQL and MySQL_Python.

```
brew install mariadb
```

To run django you should also install PIL (Python Image Library), lxml:

```
sudo pip install PIL
sudo pip install lxml
```

and gettext (Translations) using [brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install gettext
```

Comment: hmmmm but there's no way i can configure django with mysql on lion ?

Comment: You need a 64bit version of python. Then it should work. As long as you don't use any libraries that are only 32bit.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a python package called mariadb for python?

Comment: Right, you have to install mariadb using homebrew.